# Haskell: How is join a natural transformation?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

I can define a natural transformation in Haskell as:

```
h :: [a] -> Maybe a
h []    = Nothing
h (x:_) = Just x
```

and with a function k:

```
k :: Char -> Int
k = ord
```

the naturality condition is met due to the fact that:

`h . fmap k` == `fmap k . h`

Can the naturality condition of the List monad's `join` function be demonstrated in a similar way? I'm having some trouble understanding how `join`, say `concat` in particular, is a natural transformation.

Comment: Surprisingly, because of Reynolds parametricity, any reasonable polymorphic Haskell function that looks like `f a -> g a` is a natural transformation (modulo the usual issues with bottom). This means that you don't actually have to check every individual function to see if it satisfies the conditions for being a natural transformation. They are "free theorems". The place to start reading is here: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.9875

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, let's look at `concat`.

First, here's the implementation:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat = foldr (++) []
```

This parallels the structure of your `h` where `Maybe` is replaced by `[]` and, more significantly, `[]` is replaced by--to abuse syntax for a moment--`[[]]`.

`[[]]` is a functor as well, of course, but it's *not* a `Functor` instance in the way that the naturality condition uses it. Translating your example directly won't work:

`concat . fmap k` =/= `fmap k . concat`

...because both `fmap`s are working on only the outermost `[]`.

And although `[[]]` is hypothetically a valid instance of `Functor` you can't make it one directly, for practical reasons that are probably obvious.

However, you can reconstruct the correct lifting as so:

`concat . (fmap . fmap) k` == `fmap k . concat`

...where `fmap . fmap` is equivalent to the implementation of `fmap` for a hypothetical `Functor` instance for `[[]]`.

As a related addendum, `return` is awkward for the opposite reason: `a -> f a` is a natural transformation from an elided identity functor. Using `: []` the identity would be written as so:

`(:[]) . ($) k` == `fmap k . (:[])`

...where the completely superfluous `($)` is standing in for what would be `fmap` over the elided identity functor.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'd come to understand `return` by reasoning that Haskell could have required us to construct *every* value using something like `I 7` or `I [1,2,3]` etc. But perhaps that approach has its own warts.

Comment: @user643722: It's clumsy, mostly. Otherwise it's completely equivalent and converting between `I a` and `a` is trivial. The equivalent to using an explicit identity functor would be to use a `newtype` for nested lists, e.g. `newtype L2 a = L2 [[a]]` and make that an instance of `Functor`. It may help to keep in mind that the `Functor` type class can only describe a very limited subset of valid functors, namely functors from all of **Hask** to a subcategory of it defined by a single type constructor of kind `* -> *`.

Comment: Is it worth perhaps rewriting this answer using `Compose` from `transformers`? That *does* let us write a valid definition of `fmap` for `[[]]`, if you write `[[]]` as `Compose [] []`.

Comment: @ocharles: Creating a wrapper to describe functor composition has always been possible, of course. It's not really quite the same as expressing functor composition directly. If I write `(f . g)` and apply it to `x` I don't have to unwrap the result somehow to get the same value as I would from `f (g x)`.